# React dynamic import files with variable

Tags: reactjs, import, dynamic-import

I am trying to load files with variables

my current implementation:

```
const map = {
  google: import('./svg/google.svg'),
  microsoft: import('./svg/microsoft.svg')
}
const Image = ({ name }) => {
  //assume map[name] always exists
  const Component = map[name];
  return (
    <Component />
  )
}
```

the above snippet works perfectly. now the requirement is to add another 400 companies.
Well, i don't want to create & maintain a map with 400 keys.
so I am wondering if there is any better to do that? i.e. load the file with variable

something like

```
import(`./svg/${name}.svg`)
```

Comment: Do you have control over your webpack configuration or are you using something like create-react-app? I would imagine that webpack could be configured to do what you're looking for, or extended with a plugin.

Comment: @cubrr yes I have control over webpack. we are not using CRA. what kind of plugin can be used here?

Comment: @cubrr two different problems

Comment: @peaceandlove you found any solution ? for this